# How can i send null value with a datetimepicker in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, null, datetimepicker

i need your help i want to send null to my database when the datetimepicker is disabled and send the date when its enable but i just dont get it how can i do it

```
Function insertarPersona(ByVal Fecha_de_Precla As Date) As String
    Dim salida As String = "Se ha insertado correctamente"
    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into pruebasop(Fecha_de_Precla)values ('" & Fecha_de_Precla & "')", cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

and i want to insert the data depending if the  chekbox its enabled or not, sorry for my bad english

Comment: You would use DBNull.Value as the value.  Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

You use a parameter setting the value to DBNull.Value. Of course this will work only if your datatable field (Fecha_de_Precla) accepts a NULL value.

```
Function insertarPersona(ByVal Fecha_de_Precla As Date) As String
    Dim salida As String = "Se ha insertado correctamente"
    Try
        Dim cmdText = "Insert into pruebasop(Fecha_de_Precla)
                              values (@fecha)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, cn)
        if date_precla.Enabled = False then
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
        else
           cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Fecha_de_Precla
        End If
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

It is important to use the correct DataType for the parameter. Check how you have defined the table field and use the correct SqlDbType.

Comment: Hi steve, thnx for your response, i named my datetimepicker as date_precla, but ive got one more problem when i modify the code you put in here, a message appears and tells me i dont have an object reference

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, time difference probably. So on which line did you get the error message? In the snippet above the only variables that could give that error are the _cn_ connection and the date_precla itself

Comment: hey steve dont worry, the error that shows up says that the name 'dateprecla' was not declared this is the code edited 

   Dim cmdText = "Insert into pruebasop(Fecha_de_Precla)values (@fecha)"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(cmdText, cn)
            If DatePrecla.Enabled = False Then
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Fecha_de_Precla
            End If

Comment: The variable for the DateTimePicker is named _Date_Precla_ with the underscore or _dateprecla_ without?

Comment: Without it,    DatePrecla